# Programmatically define my path to graphics

Tags: graphics

My file architecture looks like the one below.

I define probably clumsily (one by one) my `graphicspath`.

1. If so, what would you advise me to do ?
2. If not, how can I use a `\foreach` to alleviate this looong list ?

```
\graphicspath{
{F:/NewOrga/_chap/chap01/_Images/}
...
{F:/NewOrga/_chap/chap55/_Images/}
{F:/NewOrga/_chap/chap56/_Images/}
}
```

(and it'll grow)

Comment: set TEXINPUTS to be `f:/NewOrga//;` then any files under that folder will be found without needing any macro looping at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Neat :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\int_step_function:nN` it's basically a one-liner.  The trickier (and even then, pretty easy) part is to format `1` as `01`.  There are several ways you can do it with proper `expl3` syntax.

```
\prg_replicate:nn { 2-\str_count:n {#1} } { 0 } #1
```

and

```
\int_compare:nNnT {#1} < { 10 } { 0 } #1
```

are examples (I'll use the latter).

```latex
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Define a function that expands to {<path>}
\cs_new:Npn \jet_tmp_addpath:n #1
  { { F:/NewOrga/_chap/chap \int_compare:nNnT {#1} < { 10 } { 0 } #1 /_Images/ } }
% apply \graphicspath to all up to (here) 56
\use:x { \exp_not:N \graphicspath { \int_step_function:nN { 56 } \jet_tmp_addpath:n } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% to make sure:
\makeatletter
\show\Ginput@path
```

The terminal shows:

```
> \Ginput@path=macro:
->{F:/NewOrga/_chap/chap01/_Images/}{F:/NewOrga/_chap/chap02/_Images/}{F:/NewOr
ga/_chap/chap03/_Images/}{F:/NewOrga/_chap/chap04/_Images/}{F:/NewOrga/_chap/ch
ap05/_Images/}{F:/NewOrga/_chap/chap06/_Images/}{F:/NewOrga/_chap/chap07/_Image
s/}{F:/NewOrga/_chap/chap08/_Images/}{F:/NewOrga/_chap/chap09/_Images/}{F:/NewO

... many more ...

chap/chap54/_Images/}{F:/NewOrga/_chap/chap55/_Images/}{F:/NewOrga/_chap/chap56
/_Images/}.
```